# Syncrify and empty folders

Tags: rsync

Perhaps I'm missing something in the configuration, but can anyone tell me how to force [Syncrify](http://web.synametrics.com/Syncrify.htm) backup empty folders?

It seems if they're empty they don't get created in the backup.

Comment: Actually, I pulled my finger out and learned how to use rsync instead.